# Database query result links should open in new window / tab instead of the same window

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, data-explorer

Most any time I use a data.stackexchange.com query, I use it so I can find many dozens of posts that I possibly need to take action on (like close vote, flag vote, etc). For example, I was just using this query to find answer to possibly flag as not an answer: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/41578/seek-and-destroy-comments-with-the-phrase-not-an-answer

As it is currently, when you click on a link that is generated by the query it opens in the same window. Please change these links to _blank so they open in a new window/tab instead.

By implementing this, it will reduce the clicks I need to do by 50.000%, and also greatly reduces the the total distance my mouse needs to travel, and the precision that requires. Thus making it more ergonomic.

[image]

Comment: Or simply hold down the ctrl key when you click the links.

Comment: Or right click and use the "open in new tab/window" from the context menu.

Comment: I don't think the website should decide it for the user. Clicking with middle mouse button, ctrl-clicking or selecting a new tab from right-click menu are all very easy solutions, but there are no obvious solutions to open a link in current tab, if the website tells you it should open a new one.

Comment: You can run this or create a Ghostscript for it: `$('div.slick-cell.l0.r0.text a').each(function(){$(this).attr('target', '_blank');})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the ability to do that now, using either the controls built into your browser (right-click menu, keyboard shortcuts) or a client script.  So, with the current implementation, people who want new tabs can get them *and* people who want the same tab can get that.  Your change takes away the choice.  To *you*, for *this query*, it might be "obviously correct", but it doesn't follow that the change is generally and universally good.

In addition, your change violates user expectations -- why, the user asks himself, do *some* links open in new tabs but not others?  It may be what he ought to do in many cases, but web sites shouldn't appear to behave randomly.  (Links in the community bulletin also open in new tabs and I've seen that trip users up.)  Users should be responsible for their own navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. SE is inconsistent about this, but *most* things open in the same tab and I think instead of adding confusion by creating more new tabs, they should reduce the confusion by changing the places where they currently do it. There may be a few *very* specialized cases where a new tab always makes sense (I think there are some in moderator tools), but IMO it's better to be very conservative with things that affect all users. (It wasn't SE, but I once had to help a relative "fix" his slow browser; turned out he had *dozens* of auto-launched tabs he hadn't noticed. Sheesh.)

Comment: Yeah, for what it's worth, I would disagree with implementing this for the reasons outlined.