# Open SEDE links in a new tab by default

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, data-explorer

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer has [some functionality](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) to generate links. Those links open in the current tab by default, which has one significant disadvantage: when you navigate back, you have to *rerun* the query. You can try this yourself by [creating a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/new), submit this example query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id AS [Post Link] FROM Posts
```

and opening the link.

Could the generated links be changed so that they always open in a new tab or window?

Comment: related wrt opening links in a new tab: [Link to the SEDE guide should open a new tab rather than changing the current URL (of the query composer)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377114/link-to-the-sede-guide-should-open-a-new-tab-rather-than-changing-the-current-ur)

Comment: Would opening in a new tab *always* be a good default? I do think it is but just checking if there are maybe cornercases where you don't want this to happen.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: [Database query result links should open in new window / tab instead of the same window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233684/database-query-result-links-should-open-in-new-window-tab-instead-of-the-same) and based on the accepted answer and comment from Tim [tag:status-declined]

Comment: Maybe as an alternative, it could display a warning message if the user attempts to navigate while the query is in edit mode.

Comment: On a second thought, that wouldn't work for queries with parameters.